# Enter button in Python turtle program is not responding

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
import random

wn = turtle.Screen() #sets the screen
wn.setup(1000,900)
wn.screensize(2000,2000)
ad = turtle.Turtle() #names the turtle
ad.shape("circle") #changes turtles or "ad's" shape
ad.speed("fastest")

r = int(60) #CHANGES THE SIZE OF THE WRITING


x = int(-950)
y = int(200)


ad.penup()
ad.goto(x,y)
def enter():
     ad.penup()
     y -= 100
     ad.goto(x,y)
wn.onkey(lambda: enter(), "Return")
wn.listen()
```

Trying to do an enter button in turtle but this wont work. 
It says that there is an error with the local variable.

Comment: show your error

Comment: `x` and `y` have a scope problem.

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment

Comment: how do I correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your immediate problem is the lack of a `global y` statement in your `enter()` function, there's a lot of *noise* in your code that we should eliminate to make it a better [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import random  # not used so leave out of SO question example
r = int(60) # ditto

x = int(-950)  # int() not needed for ints
y = int(200)  # ditto

wn.onkey(lambda: enter(), "Return")  # lambda not needed
```

Although we *could* fix this with the addition of a `global y` statement, I prefer to simply interrogate the turtle itself and avoid the global:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def enter():
    ad.sety(ad.ycor() - 100)

X, Y = -950, 200

wn = Screen()
wn.setup(1000, 1000)  # visible field
wn.screensize(2000, 2000)  # total field

ad = Turtle("circle")
ad.speed("fastest")
ad.penup()
ad.goto(X, Y)

wn.onkey(enter, "Return")
wn.listen()

wn.mainloop()
```

Note, you positioned the turtle off the visible portion of the screen so you need to scroll to the left side of the window to see the turtle cursor.  Once you do, you can move it down by hitting, "Return".